# G*Power and simulation produce very different sample size estimates for a Poisson regression

Tags: simulation, statistical-power, poisson-regression, gpower

I've been attempting to conduct a sample size calculation for a Poisson regression. G*Power produced a sample size of 472.

Parameters for G*Power

Tails = 2

Exp(B1) = 1.233

alpha = 0.05

Power = 0.8

Base Rate Exp(B0) = 1.37

Mean exposure = 1

R2 from other variables = 0

X Distribution = Binomial

X parm π = 0.5

However, when I try to simulate a sample size calculation in R, a sample size of 472 tends to result in about 25% power

```
N_per_grp = 236
significant_count = 0

for (i in 1:10000) {

  grp_1 = data.frame(rep(1,N_per_grp), rpois(N_per_grp, 1.233))
  names(grp_1) = c("grp", "outcome")

  grp_0 = data.frame(rep(0,N_per_grp), rpois(N_per_grp, 1.37))
  names(grp_0) = c("grp", "outcome")

  df = rbind(grp_1, grp_0)

  fit = summary(glm(outcome ~ grp, data = df, family = poisson(link = "log")))

  p = fit$coefficients[2,4]

  if (p <= .05) {
    significant_count = significant_count + 1
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Shouldn't the rate in the treatment group be 1.233 * 1.37? The way you're simulating it now, there's a base rate of 1.37, and a RR of about 1.233/1.37 = 0.9...

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. I was interpreting the Exp(B1) in G*Power as the rate in the intervention group

Comment: It's the rate, relative to the control group. When you change that do you get consistent answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not programming the relative rate of 1.233 correctly. The rate in group 1 needs to 1.233 times larger than the rate in group 0...Not just 1.233

```
set.seed(1)
N_per_grp = 236
significant_count = 0

for (i in 1:10000) 
{
 grp_1 = data.frame(rep(1,N_per_grp), rpois(N_per_grp, 1.233*1.37))
 names(grp_1) = c("grp", "outcome")

 grp_0 = data.frame(rep(0,N_per_grp), rpois(N_per_grp, 1.37))
 names(grp_0) = c("grp", "outcome")

 df = rbind(grp_1, grp_0)

 fit = summary(glm(outcome ~ grp, data = df, family = poisson(link = "log")))

 p = fit$coefficients[2,4]

 if (p <= .05) {
   significant_count = significant_count + 1
 }
}
significant_count/10000
[1] 0.7937
```

Looks about like 80% power to me....